# Can Master of the Unseen Hand telekinetically wield multiple weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

I have come up with a pretty crazy idea after I have been inspired by an image on deviantart.

[image]

It turned out to be an actual character in Legend of the Cryptids mobile card game. She is called [Wildea of the Seven Spears](http://legendofthecryptids.wikia.com/wiki/Wildea_of_the_Seven_Spears).  Her fighting style is described thus: "She brandish her weapons as if they were extensions of her body, sweeping across the battlefield in a whirlwind of death."

I've immedietaly thought about the class of **Master of the Unseen Hand**, which utilises combat use of telekinesis.

Master of the Unseen Hand grants a following class feature

> **Telekinetic Wielder (Ex):** A master of the unseen hand develops the ability to wield weapons with his telekinetic power. By maintaining concentration on the combat maneuver version of telekinesis, a master of the unseen hand of 2nd level or higher can make a single attack with an unattended weapon or one he is holding, moving the weapon up to 20 feet before the attack. [...]

**Would it be possible to telekinetically wield 4 or 5 weapons and attack with all of them? I am talking here about actual fighting, not mere hurling them!** Are there any feats or other classes that would be required?

If there are some alternative ways to achieve it, please include them. (Yes, I am aware of dancing weapon feature).

Comment: Are you trying to dual wield in the sense of making multiple attacks per turn, or just having several weapons "out" to choose between?

Comment: @SirTechSpec more like pentaple wield and multiple attacks.

Comment: I don't know where the art's from. Is the figure *supposed* to be wielding the weapons telekinetically or [is the figure merely hurling them telekinetically?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83038/8610)

Comment: I did some reverse image hunting and found the source.  She's a character from a mobile card game called Legend of the Cryptids.  I also included a line from the wiki describing her fighting style.  I voted to close as unclear, because I can't tell from your description what exactly you are trying to do with this character.  Clearly you want multiple weapons wielded telekinetically, but you don't make it clear what your other mechanical goals are for this character, and what counts as "wielding multiple weapons" for you.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl Actually I had no idea, I just enjoyed the [picture itself](http://avvart.deviantart.com/art/Ulia-442320386/).

Answer (score 3):

## It Can Be Simulated

Using *telekinesis* to manipulate objects with the *Combat Maneuver*, the Master of the Unseen Hand (MotUH) can use:

#### Telekinetic Wielder (Ex):

> A master of the unseen hand develops the ability to wield weapons with his telekinetic power. By maintaining concentration on the combat maneuver version of telekinesis, a master of the unseen hand of 2nd level or higher can make a single attack with an unattended weapon or one he is holding, moving the weapon up to 20 feet before the attack. Resolve the attack as normal, except that the weapon's movement doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity. The master of the unseen hand's base attack bonus on this attempt is equal to his caster level plus his Intelligence modifier (if a wizard) or Charisma modifier (if a sorcerer or a creature with the telekinesis supernatural or spell-like ability). Any weapon-related feats the master of the unseen hand has (such as Weapon Focus and Power Attack) do not apply when he's telekinetically wielding a weapon.
>
> The weapon wielded can be one the master of the unseen hand took from a foe on a successful disarm attempt.

On the face of it, this requires adjudication in order to use more than one weapon in such a fashion. It's completely reasonable to say that the MotUH *can* indeed wield more than one weapon with this ability, by allowing each attack to use different weapons, but the doesn't *explicitly* allow it.

The Full Attack Telekinesis ability coupled with the above TK Wielder, however implies that she *could* control as many weapons as she has attacks:

> ...When using the combat maneuver version of telekinesis or wielding a weapon telekinetically, the master of the unseen hand can make a full attack, potentially attacking, bull rushing, disarming, grappling, or tripping more than once per round...

Thus at CL 20, she can disarm 3 foes, at diminishing bonuses as normal for iterative attacks, and then attack one of them with a weapon. That's explicit. Implicit there is the possibility that she could disarm 2 foes, and attack each of them once. It's not a real stretch from there to her 4 attacks being available from 4 separate weapons.

Permitting the individual manipulation of multiple weapons in this manner runs afoul of a few issues, mostly regarding movement and flanking. Each allowed weapon could move 20', at a potentially *huge* range from the MotUH, without attacks of opportunity. Plus, opponents don't appear to have a method to disarm the MotUH, or otherwise impede these movements. Additionally, 2 or more weapons might permit the MotUH to flank an opponent by herself. These considerations are not *huge*, but would be a possible sore point for those with balance concerns.

#### Violently Thrusting

The Combat Maneuver-cum-Telekinetic Wielder rules does not have specific rules allowing the manipulation of more than one creature or object, except through interpretation of the Full-Attack TK mechanic. However, a 4th level MotUH also gets to use Violent Thrust without ending the effect, once per 1d4 rounds. [Improved] Violent thrust allows the MotUH to:

> ...hurl one object or creature per caster level (maximum 15) that are within range and all within 10 feet of each other toward any target within 10 feet per level of all the objects. You can hurl up to a total weight of 25 pounds per caster level (maximum 375 pounds at 15th level).
>
> You must succeed on attack rolls (one per creature or object thrown) to hit the target with the items, using your [caster level in place of] your base attack bonus + your Intelligence modifier (if a wizard) or Charisma modifier (if a sorcerer). Weapons cause standard damage (with no Strength bonus [though you add your spellcasting stat modifier as a bonus to the damage]; note that arrows or bolts deal damage as daggers of their size when used in this manner).

("[ ]" brackets are modified rules from the MotUH's description)

### Why This Is part of the Answer

Violent Thrust usually ends the effect, so the objects so used would fall to the ground or remain impaled in the MotUH's targets. Since her Improved Violent Thrust doesn't end the TK effect, she *could* potentially retain control of the hurled objects, since the *telekinesis* effect continues after her thrust. *Telekinesis* doesn't talk about maneuvering or manipulating more than one object at a time, however, except regarding Violent Thrust, and Full-attack Telekinesis.

---

### Unrequested Philosophy and House Rules

Allowing full-attacking with multiple weapons would diminish the utility of the Violent Thrust, Improved or not.

Because of the "cool factor" this DM *might* allow multiple weapons to be used, 1 per CL (max. 15) as per the Violent thrust limitations. This would operate using [Two-weapon fighting rules](http://www.dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#two-weapon-fighting), with full associated penalties of full-attacks with 1 weapon at -6, 1 attack with each of the others at -10, with *no* mitigation for light weapons or any [Multiweapon Fighting](http://www.dndsrd.net/monsterFeats.html#multiweapon-fighting) feat, nor ways to use feats to iterate the secondary weapon attacks.

This is because Telekinetic Wielder says:

> ...Any weapon-related feats the master of the unseen hand has (such as Weapon Focus and Power Attack) do not apply when he's telekinetically wielding a weapon.

The lack of mitigation for light weapons feels like it follows the spirit of the above rule. Plus it throws my cruel, heartless exterior into *sharp relief*.

I'd rule that She'd be limited to a range of 10'/CL, and the weapons must be within 10' of each other, as per Violent Thrust. This would give her some, though greatly diminished, use of the weapons in between uses of Violent Thrust.

These house-rules don't appear to be either *explicitly or implicitly* supported by the text, but I feel that they are reasonably extrapolated from it and follow its spirit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any method in the RAW by which this would be possible, however I could definitely be convinced by a player to allow something like this in my games simply because it's a cool idea.

The big balancing point for me is that in order to use this ability you must succeed on a *Concentration* Check to maintain the Telekinesis spell each round. I think it would be reasonable to simply increase the DC of the Concentration check for each additional attack/weapon the caster attempted.

As for RAW, the Master of the Unseen Hand actually gains *Full Attack Telekinesis* at level 3 which grants the ability to make a full attack with his/her combat maneuver version of Telekinesis and an extra attack for every 5 points of attack bonus above +1. Keep in mind that your attack bonus when you are using Telekinesis is not your BAB but rather your caster level. Instead of adding Strength on attacks you use your Intelligence Modifier for Wizards or Charisma Modifier for Sorcerers. RAW doesn't really specify that you must use the same weapon for this full round attack, so you could theoretically use multiple weapons if your GM allowed it.

---

All of that aside, I really don't suggest playing a MotUH. The class is really focused on one trick, and even with that trick it isn't very useful (compared to other prestige classes or 5 extra levels in Wizard/Sorcerer.)

Comment: So according to this, a caster with a INT of 20, and a casting level of 20th, would get 4 attacks?

Comment: According to the RAW you mean? Yeah. Look up Master of the Unseen Hand. I didn't want to quote it directly because I'm not sure if that's allowed with 3.5 material.

Comment: @GreedyRadish It's cool to quote stuff directly. Just don't quote so much that it obviates a casual reader's need for the book. The entire prestige class, for example, would be too much. One ability of the prestige class? [That's probably fine](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/357/8610), but you can be as careful with that *probably* as you want.