# Can a Master of Unseen Hand wield oversized weapons with telekinesis? And would he have the -4 on the attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, weapons, prestige-class

I'm planning a MoUH as dungeon boss for my campaign and I was figuring out this kickass fling mage in a black cloak that has at first a huge object hidden in straps on his back. Suddenly he levitates away while swinging this huge "chunk of metal" (quote intended) with his bare mind. 
I must say that regardless of the rules I'm gonna do it but I was wondering what kind of malus I should give him.

(The -4 was only my guess, I know that RAW you can't wield a Huge sized Greatsword or something like that but only because you don't have big enough hands, which telekinesis doesn't need)

Comment: Hello and welcome! I see you have already taken the [tour], well done! I made an edit to your question in an attempt to improve it. If I changed the meaning of the question or you simply don't like the changes feel free to rollback.

Comment: Oh thank you a lot! I'm not English and I made some mispelling. Good Job

Comment: Did you mean that the mage is encountered as a flying mage, or that he's fling mage, who throws stuff?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83038/8610).

Comment: Related: [Can Master of the Unseen Hand telekinetically wield multiple weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87330/41726)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Maybe Probably Yes

The only limit on wielding a weapon telekintetically is the weight limit of whatever telekinesis effect the wielder is using.

*However*, see the following line:

> ...can make a single attack with an **unattended weapon or one he is holding**, moving the weapon up to 20 feet before the attack. Resolve the attack as normal, except that the weapon's movement doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity....

The bold part implies - but not states - that it should be a weapon normally sized for the wielder.

If that statement is determined to not impede this amusing and fun-sounding idea, I do not believe that there is anything else in the class or rules which would prevent the telekinetic from using as big and bad a chunk of metal as they can find.

Bonus points if you have an array of extra objects for selection choice: giant golf club, a pillar from a holy temple (bonus holy damage, right?), the arm off of a titanic statue, an entire suit of armor, random assortment of fish (long-ago robotech campaign reference), an anvil, an anchor, a bathtub, a small boat, a kitchen sink, and so forth.

---

Also, as a side comment, the Master of the Unseen Hand is one of the very few "mage" classes that a psionicist can actually and legally qualify for as written, making it one of my personal favorites. I managed to make a D&D version of a Jedi once partly using this class.

Comment: Actually, it says either unattended, *or* one he is holding. I don't see the implication that the weapon must be sized for you as a very strong one; it's really only saying that you can't take a weapon carried or held by someone else. Regarding the improvised weapons you mention... as long as they fit within the limits of the TK spell/MotUH ability, yep.

Comment: I reeeally like your suggestions, in fact my first idea was to have a big statue and the mage would have ripped off the stone greatsword in the hand of the statue.

Comment: @Chemus I agree with you actually. I was simply stating that due to the wildly varying interpretations we see rules get put through that it "*could*" be interpreted that way... though perhaps I should have made it more clear that I absolutely would not do so myself.