# How does the Telekinesis spell's Violent Thrust option work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Part of the [Telekinesis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinesis/) spell description says:

> **Violent Thrust:** Alternatively, the spell energy can be spent in a single round. You can hurl one object or creature per caster level (maximum 15) that are within range and all within 10 feet of each other toward any target within 10 feet per level of all the objects. You can hurl up to a total weight of 25 pounds per caster level (maximum 375 pounds at 15th level).
>
> You must succeed on attack rolls (one per creature or object thrown) to hit the target with the items, using your base attack bonus + your Intelligence modifier (if a wizard) or Charisma modifier (if a sorcerer). Weapons cause standard damage (with no Strength bonus; note that arrows or bolts deal damage as daggers of their size when used in this manner). Other objects cause damage ranging from 1 point per 25 pounds (for less dangerous objects) to 1d6 points of damage per 25 pounds (for hard, dense objects). Objects and creatures that miss their target land in a square adjacent to the target.

1. Are there penalties per object thrown after the first one?
2. Do you still need Point Blank Shot and Precise Shot to shoot into melee?
3. Can you you use Sneak Attack with this method of attack?

Comment: [You may be interested in this similar *D&D 3.5* question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83038/8610)

Comment: You may also need to seperate this into 2-3 different questions. As written, you may get answers that are correct on one point but incorrect on another.

Answer (score 2):

1. Are there penalties per object thrown after the first one?

No penalties are noted, so no penalty is incurred. This is not a Full Attack, and does not use iterative attack rules.

> ...one object or creature per caster level (maximum 15)...
>   "...using your base attack bonus + your Intelligence modifier (if a wizard) or Charisma modifier (if a sorcerer)."

No creature I'm aware of gets 15 attacks in a single round; applying penalties to these attacks would quickly make this portion of the spell impossible to use.

2. Do you still need Point Blank Shot and Precise Shot to shoot into melee?

Debatable, so ask your GM. If you have the luxury of deciding for your game, I believe the correct answer is that you *would* apply the benefits of Point-Blank Shot or penalties for not having Precise Shot. The confusion comes from the spell referencing an "attack roll", not a "ranged attack roll". However, you *are making ranged attacks*, so regardless of if the spell calls them that or not, they should be treated as such unless the book says otherwise.

3. Can you you use Sneak Attack with this method of attack?

This one is more straight forward. Absolutely! Unless your GM table-rules against it, this spell causes you to perform attack rolls, and the Sneak Attack class feature is fairly ambiguous, only indicating that the triggering action be an attack.

> The [class]’s **attack** deals extra damage anytime her target would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not), or when the rogue flanks her target.

You must still meet the other requirements, such as being within 30ft of the target (arguably, the object(s) thrown must also be within 30ft) and the target must be denied their Dexterity toward your attack, can't have Concealment (Total Concealment for Unchained), etc.